# binding not working tkinter python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

so I'm working on a rubics cube timer in python 3 (using tkinter).

I am trying to make it so that when you press space, the timer stops
(originally i tried to do this for starting and stopping but i found it too hard) 
I have tried to bind  the space key to my Stop function but it either returns an error (when I ommit a set of parenthesis after naming the function to bind to, it for some stupid reason thinks I'm passing 2 arguments. idk why this happens) or doesnt work at all. 
here is my code, Thx in advance for the solution.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
""" Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()


    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
    """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0
            print("fsddaewSDGNFHRAW") # a test to see if it works

    def Reset(self):                                  
    """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    root.bind("<space>",sw.Stop()) # this is where i tried to bind
    # if i did this:
    #root.bind("<space>",sw.stop) it would say im passing 2 parameters instead of one (self)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

First, the `bind` function needs the function itself as an argument. Since you have the `()` on the end, you are passing the result of running the function, in this case `None`. Just leave those off:

```
root.bind("<space>",sw.Stop)
```

Second, the function that `bind` calls must accept an event argument. So you need to define it like this:

```
def Stop(self, event=None):
```